# SQL Server If statement assigning values

Tags: sql-server, case

Please see the pseudocode below. Basically what I'm trying to do is write a statement that when an account number contains one of the specified codes it will assign that Level to the entire account not to just that one row.

I've tried using a case statement in a CTE and few other options and I'm not having much luck. Any help is appreciated.

```
if AcctNo contains Code = '1' 
then level = '1'
elif AcctNo contains Code = '2'
then level = '2'


AcctNo  Code  charge   level
1       2       50     Null
1       17      60     Null
1       28      61     Null
1       36      62     Null
1       18      63     Null
```

Desired Results

```
 AcctNo  Code  charge    level
    1       2       50     2
    1       17      60     2
    1       28      61     2
    1       36      62     2
    1       18      63     2
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site, please post actual code instead of pseudo-code. Table definitions, sample data and expected output would help too.

Comment: And what if there are two rows, one with `code=1` and another with `code=2` (and many other rows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a really basic level it would look like this

```
UPDATE TableName
SET [level] = CASE WHEN AcctNo = '1' THEN '1'
                    WHEN AcctNo = '2' THEN '2'
                    ELSE 'DefaultVal' END
```

or

```
UPDATE TableName
SET [level] = CASE AcctNo WHEN '1' THEN '1'
                    WHEN '2' THEN '2'
                    ELSE 'DefaultVal' END
```

Depending on if you only need the one column in your conditions or if it's more complicated than that.

**Edit**  On looking at your expected data it looks like what you want is this:

```
WITH Levels AS (SELECT AcctNo, Level, 
        MIN(CASE WHEN code IN (1,2,3,4,5) THEN code ELSE NULL END) 
                OVER (PARTITION BY AcctNo) AS MinCode
        FROM Test)
UPDATE Levels
SET level = MinCode
```

Note: This assumes that you want the minimum code for a given AcctNo.

If you just want a select statement to test then change it to this:

```
WITH Levels AS (SELECT AcctNo, Code, Charge, Level, 
        MIN(CASE WHEN code IN (1,2,3,4,5) THEN code ELSE NULL END) 
                OVER (PARTITION BY AcctNo) AS MinCode
        FROM Test)
SELECT * FROM Levels
```

Comment: The list of codes that relate to a level are specifically 1-5. The rest of the codes are ancillary

Comment: @KennethFisher thank you very much your solution got me my desired result, now I just need to get it so  i can easily update it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you mean [contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)
I think you mean if any code has that value
I think this is what you are looking for

```
update t2  
set t2.level = t1.code 
from table t1 
join table t2 
      on t2.AcctNo = t1.AcctNo 
     and             t1.Code in (1,2)
```

If an AcctNo had Code both 1 and 2 then this would be non-deterministic

If you need one (actually 2) to win then

```
update t2  
set t2.level = t1.code 
from table t1 
join table t2 
      on t2.AcctNo = t1.AcctNo 
     and             t1.Code in (1);
update t2  
set t2.level = t1.code 
from table t1 
join table t2 
      on t2.AcctNo = t1.AcctNo 
     and             t1.Code in (2);
```

Comment: Frisbee i'm not sure on the proper operator, that is where my problem stems from. What I mean is if a certain account number has a code related to it in any of the different row than that set code should be the level.

Comment: The data set i listed is a extremely dumbed down version of what i'm looking for. I do use tables, however i'm using several CTEs and several tables in my query right now to get the information I need.

Comment: Answer is only as good as the question